# Create google calendar on behalf of user

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am developing a java Springboot Backend application.
In Which I have multiple users for whom I need to create calendar event and send mail using their gmail id. I am only able to use credentials for a single user for authentication of google api.

Is there any way that I can achieve creating calendar event on mail, using client's gmail id, without having to get consent from the client from the UI each time with google api?

Also please advice if there is a way to get authenticated to use google api's without having to interact with the UI.

Comment: Do you mean authenticate as in the API? Or do you mean to operate on users data without them having to log in?

Comment: I want to add calendar event on behalf of user and send the mail using gmail id of the user, however it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google calendar data is private user data, in order to create an even on a users calendar you need permission of the user who owns that calendar.

To do that we use something called Oauth2,  With Oauth2 your application will request permission of the user to access there data and the authorization server will return to you a token giving you permission to access the api on behalf of the user.

There is no way to access private user data without the owner granting you permission to access it.

> without having to get consent from the client from the UI each time with google api

Now one of the things you can do is request offline access of the user, if the user grants you offline access you will be given a refresh token which you can use at a later date to request a new access token.  With the access token you can make changes to the users calendar without them actually being there running your application.

## DATA_STORE_DIR for user storage

This code should be close it was altered a bit from the sample for google analytics but should show you how to use DATA_STORE_DIR to store the user credentials for use later.

```
/**
 * A simple example of how to access the Google calendar API.
 */
public class HelloCalendar {
  // Path to client_secrets.json file downloaded from the Developer's Console.
  // The path is relative to HelloCalendar.java.
  private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_RESOURCE = "client_secrets.json";

  // The directory where the user's credentials will be stored.
  private static final File DATA_STORE_DIR = new File(
      System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/hello_calendar");

  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Hello Calendar";
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  private static NetHttpTransport httpTransport;
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Calendar service = initializeCalendar();

      // do stuff here 
      printResponse(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  /**
   * Initializes an authorized calendar service object.
   *
   * @return The Calendar service object.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException
   */
  private static Calendar initializeCalendar() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

    // Load client secrets.
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(Calendar.class
            .getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_RESOURCE)));

    // Set up authorization code flow for all authorization scopes.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
        .Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            CalendarScopes.all()).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
        .build();

    // Authorize.
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
        new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("THISISTHEUSERNAME");
    // Construct the Analytics Reporting service object.
    return new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }
```

Comment: I changed the directory path and credentials for different users and it works fine for multiple user. Thank you.